# AJAX Post call using json

Tags: php, ajax, json

I need some help with a JSON object and the Ajax call using it. I need to pass this data to update my database for some purpose:

JSON string:

```
[{"id":"1"},{"id":"10"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"},{"id":"4"},{"id":"5"},{"id":"6"},{"id":"7"},{"id":"8"},{"id":"9"}]
```

I am using AJAX Post. My code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "hello_world.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(jsonString),
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        alert("Call success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + "\n" +
            "Message: " + xhr.statusText + "\n" +
            "Response: " + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError);
    }
});
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST))
   {
     $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
        echo $decoded;
   }

?>
```

Comment: `data: { data: jsonString }` might help

Comment: Yes send an object with key data as you are processing data at the php side.

Comment: Stringify the data before sending ajax refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($json, TRUE);
var_export($decoded); # for testing else use echo json_encode($decoded);
```